# What is the difference between org.springframework.security.oauth and org.codehaus.spring-security-oauth?

Tags: java, maven, oauth, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am trying to learn Oauth authentication with Spring Security and just found two versions of spring-security-oauth library.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.spring-security-oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>3.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M6</version>
</dependency>
```

I was wondering if anyone could please tell me the difference and which the preferred one is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [web site tells what it's about](http://spring-security-oauth.codehaus.org/).

> This project has been adopted into SpringSource as an official
>   extension for Spring Security. Active feature development has moved to
>   that location.
>
> You're welcome to continue to use the Codehaus artifacts, but be aware
>   that any new features aren't being developed here. This has
>   implications for those still using Spring Security 2.x, as the new
>   development is only being done in support for Spring Security 3.x.